# How to update User status after automatically logout on Yii framework 2 when user is inactive for awhile?

Tags: authentication, yii2, logout, status

On Yii framework 2, I set the User status to 1 after logging in and to 2 after manual logging out as following.

```
//after logging in
$user->status = 1; 
$user->save(true, ['status']);

//after manual logging out
$user->status = 2; 
$user->save(true, ['status']);
```

But Yii framework 2 has a mechanism to automatically clear the login session after user is inactive for awhile. How can I then update the User status in this case?

Comment: I had same task, I solved with ajax

Answer (score 1):

Do it in `afterLogout()` method in class inherited from
`Yii\web\User`?